# Why is a process stable only when the cointegrating rank of its VECM equal to the dimension of its process?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model

According to [this book](http://www.afriheritage.org/TTT/2%20New%20Introduction%20to%20Multiple%20Time%20Series%20Analysis.pdf), page 248, it is because $|I_K-A_1-...-A_p|=|-\Pi|$ (reverse polynomial), which is unequal to 0. I have a questions regarding this argument:
Wouldn't  $|I_K-A_1-...-A_p|=|-\Pi|=0$ have a root with modulus smaller than 1?